# Magento1.9 : order by Zend_Db_Expr showing error while reindexing catalog_product_flat index

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection

I have created a custom script to display products on home page filter by product ids.

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $product_ids))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
```

But products showing on frontend in entity_id (ASC) orders. To order by product_ids array I found below code and it is working :

```
$_productCollection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('FIELD(entity_id, ' . $product_ids.')'))
```

But whenever `php shell/indexer.php -reindex catalog_product_flat` index is in processing this line shows error on frontend `there has been error processing your request`.

This error still coming If catalog flat tables setting are disabled in admin panel and no index is in processing state.

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution. The error was coming because of unknown column. Just changed `entity_id` to `e.entity_id` in order query as below :

```
$_productCollection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('FIELD(e.entity_id, ' . $product_ids.')'))
```

And the code is working now.

Hope this will help someone.